# How to use Clusterkraf in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use Clusterkraf in my android project https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf , I imported it successfully too. I set up three markers with the same location. However when I check the map, I see 1 marker. I expected to see a blue icon with a 3 on it.

I think the clustering function is not working somehow. Do I need some special code to configure it?

This is what I have so far:

In this, I get a list of points, and then I make the list of `InputPoint` objects, then I use it to create the clusterkraf map. What else do I need to do so that I get the clustering feature to work?

```
public void MakeMarkerArray(ArrayList<ObjMarker> locationList) {
    LatLng latlong;
    ObjPoint point;
    BitmapDescriptor bm = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);

    for(ObjMarker po : locationList) {
        latlong = AddressToLatLong(po.location);
        if (latlong != null) {
            point = new ObjPoint(latlong);
            inputPoints.add(new InputPoint(point.latLng, point));

            //Marker newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).icon(bm));
            //markerID.put(newmarker.getId(), po);
        }
    }

    if (map != null && inputPoints != null && inputPoints.size() > 0) {
        com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.Options options = new com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.Options();
        // customize the options before you construct a Clusterkraf instance
        clusterkraf = new Clusterkraf(map, options, inputPoints);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Compare to [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). In the simplest case you only need to [call `GoogleMap.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings())`](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/develop/android-maps-extensions-demo/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/demo/SimpleMapActivity.java#L34).

Comment: I totally feel you, the api of clusterkraf is just inconvenient. Here is an updated link to the lib Maicej mentioned:  https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to follow this comment:

```
// customize the options before you construct a Clusterkraf instance
```

If you don't set certain options, you only get default red marker out of the library.

In particular you need to implement `MarkerOptionsChooser` and add it to `Options`. See [`ToastedMarkerOptionsChooser.java`](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/blob/master/sample/src/com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/sample/ToastedMarkerOptionsChooser.java) for an example implementation.

Comment: I was looking at the sample code, but I am having no luck understanding how its done. Do I need to import any of the files from Sample into my project, like I already have the `library` project imported. I tried copying the functions into my code, but its getting errors about undefined classes. It feels like I need to import the whole Sample into my project. Can you show me code here please on how to enable the clustering? I'm very lost...